# Using Excel to create a date series for a job on the same 2 days every week

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, date

I want to create a calendar showing ONLY all the Wednesdays and Thursdays in a year with their date, so for example:

Wed 25 Sept

Thu 26 Sept

Wed 2 October

Thu 3 October

etc.

I thought it would be a simple fill function!

Comment: well, since Excel stores dates as numbers, you can simply iterate a date that is Wed and simply add 7 to it over and over again.

Comment: Read [this article](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/681891-first-monday-of-year.html) how to get first Wednesday of year. The Thursday is one day later, the next Wednesday is 7 days later.

Answer (score 0):

The formula to get your first Wednesday of the year could be (based on [this article](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/681891-first-monday-of-year.html)):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1); 1; 8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1); 1; 4))
```

(assuming that `A1` has the year you are referring to).

The next day is Thursday, so `A3` has

```
= A2 + 1
```

The next Wednesday would be `A4`

```
= A2 + 7
```

Now mark `A3` and `A4` and pull down to propagate.